# Any way to add 4K support to a late 2012 iMac?

Tags: imac, 4k, display

I have this late 2012, 27" iMac (model iMac13,2) and I want to connect that to a 4K UHD TV because I am willing to create 4K stuff.

Apparently this iMac is unable to output 4K resolution, right?

If this is true, my question is: is there something I can attach to one of its thunderbolt ports (an external video board or something) that can make this iMac support 4K for cheaper as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model iMac offered three graphics card options:

- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 660M
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 675MX
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 680MX

In terms of graphics memory these cards provided 512MB, 1GB and 2GB respectively.

Strictly speaking all these cards are capable of a maximum digital resolution of 4,096 x 2,160. However, your model iMac was only capable of 2,560 x 1,440 internal resolution, and up to 2,560 x 1,600 for external displays.

I'm not sure for the exact reason of the apparent discrepancy, so I can't guarantee there'd be absolutely no way to achieve what you want. However, I very much doubt it'd be economical to achieve.